# Virgule avant un « que » corrélatif et aprés des éléments coordonnés sur lesquels est imposée une restriction par « ne »

Tags: négation, ponctuation, coordination

La formulation suivante me pose un petit problème.

> de toute ma vie je n'ai apparemment jamais lu, entendu et bien sûr utilisé que la dernière forme.

Est-ce qu'il faut  une virgule après « utilisé », est-ce qu'il n'en faut pas, ou bien est-ce qu'elle serait facultative ?

Comment: À propos du titre de ta question : dans ta phrase il n'y a pas de négation grammaticale. *Que* fait partie de l'adverbe restrictif *ne...que*, équivalent sémantique de *seulement*. C'est uniquement *jamais* qui porte la négation (qui est donc sémantique). Si tu écris *de toute ma vie je n'ai apparemment  lu, entendu et bien sûr utilisé que la dernière forme* la phrase ne contient plus de négation sémantique, par contre, bien sûr,  tu peux te poser  exactement la même question au sujet de la virgule.

Comment: Ici *ne que* est un adverbe restrictif, par ex. https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/podcast/exercice_ne_que.html http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2466. Je regarde la GGF « L'adverbe restrictif *que* se construit avec *ne* mais n'est pas une négation. La phrase comportant *ne ... que..* n'est pas négative [...] sa contribution sémantique est identique à celle de *seulement* ». Si je répondais à ta question je dirais que la virgule est facultative, moi je la mettrais mais ce n'est qu'une question de prosodie.

Comment: @None Merci bien pour ajuster ça. Il y aurait aussi l'analyse alternative selon laquelle on considèrerait « ne … que » en tant qu'adverbe ?

Comment: La GGF le met sous le chapeau adverbe restrictif. D'autres (BDL) disent « adverbe *ne* suivi de la conjonction *que* », ce bon vieux Grevisse parle de *ne... que* comme une locution. À mon avis peu importe, l'essentiel étant que ça marque la restriction et que ça n'est ni affirmatif ni négatif (on le trouve dans les 2 types de phares)

Comment: Je n'ai pas de référence, mais ça m'étonnerait qu'il y ait une règle pour la virgule dans un cas aussi précis. Personnellement je ne crois pas que je l'aurais mise non plus, simplement car s'il y avait un seul verbe au lieu de trois, il n'y aurait pas de virgule. J'ai aussi l'impression que mettre la virgule ajouterait une séparation directement où on s'attend à une suite logique. Évidemment c'est débatable, mais en général, avec ou sans virgule, ce "que" saute toujours un peu aux yeux. À l'oral, le "que" serait prononcer plus intensément.

Comment: Je te disais deux grosses bêtises. 1) Dans mon premier commentaire – à ma décharge je cherchais à justifier ton emploi du mot négation (c'est pédagogique de chercher d'où viennent les erreurs) –  il n'y avait même pas de négation sémantique dans ta phrase, jamais ici veut dire toujours. de toute ma vie je n'ai apparemment toujours lu, entendu et bien sûr utilisé que la dernière forme !  2) Dans le commentaire précédent celui-ci je disais qu'on trouvait *ne...que* restrictif  dans les 2 types de phrases, idiotie, impossible dans des phrases négatives, on met  seulement à la place.